# convergence in capacity implies $\gamma$-convegence

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $A_n$ a sequence of quasi-open sets and $A$ a quasi- open set contained in a ball $B$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$. Let $u_A$ the unique solution in $H_0^1(A)$ of the equation $-\Delta u=1$. It means that $$ \int_A \nabla u_A\nabla\varphi =\int_A \varphi\qquad \forall \varphi\in H_0^1(A).  $$ Let us assume that $cap(A\Delta An)$ goes to $0$. I have to prove that $u_{n}$ converges to $u_A$ in $L^2(B)$. $cap$ of a set $E$ is defined as the infimum of $\int{\mathbb{R}^N} u^2+|\nabla u|^2$ over all possible $u\in H_0^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ such that $u\ge 1$ on $E$. $A \Delta A_n$ is defined as $A\backslash An \cup An\backslash A$ and a set is said to be quasi-open if for every $\epsilon$, $\exists A_\epsilon $ open set such that $cap(A\Delta A_\epsilon)<\epsilon$ and $A\subseteq A\epsilon$. $u_n$ is defined as the unique solution in $H_0^1(A_n)$ of the equation above. A function $u$ belongs to $H_0^1(A)$ (A quasi-open) if $u\in H_0^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and $u=0$ outside $A$ up to a set of null capacity